# Square Polynomials

Tags: polynomials

The question I'm trying to solve requires a polynomial of degree $2$, where $P(1)$, $P(2)$, $P(3)$ and $P(4)$ all equal (non-zero) square numbers, but $P(n)$ doesn't (where $n > 4$)

Thanks

Comment: P(1), P(2), P(3) and P(4) are all different square numbers.

Comment: Not necessarily $P(1)=P(2)=P(3)=P(4)$.  We could have $P(1)=1, P(2)=4, P(3)=4, P(4)=1$, all nonzero squares, but then $P($any other integer$)$ is negative.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry. I read it as "$P(1), P(2), P(3),P(4)$ all equal"  square numbers. Yes, this should be happening, I'll try to come up with an example.

Comment: Sorry, that's my mistake.  Thanks very much.

Comment: The body says the four numbers are equal, the comment says the four numbers are all different. If they are really supposed to be different, please edit the body accordingly.

Comment: Are you still here, 314? Any thoughts on Nick's answer? or on my comment?

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear if the following polynomial is satisfactory to you. It has rational coefficients and a negative leading coefficient:

$$P(x) = \frac{- 13 x^2}{2}+\frac{129 x}{2}-54$$

Then we can evaluate this polynomial on $1, 2, \ldots, 10$ to get $4,49,81,100,106,99,79,46,0,-59$. After this point is negative so it is clear the first 4 points are distinct squares and no other positive integers yield squares.

Answer (score 1):

$P(x)=-420x^2+420x+5329$ has $P(1)=5329=73^2$, $P(2)=4489=67^2$, $P(3)=2809=53^2$, $P(4)=289=17^2$, and $P(n)<0$ for $n\ge5$.

$P(x)=-4980x^2+12180x+47089$ has $P(1)=54289=233^2$, $P(2)=51529=227^2$, $P(3)=38809=197^2$, $P(4)=16129=127^2$, and $P(n)<0$ for $n\ge5$.

See D Allison, [On square values of quadratics](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/mathematical-proceedings-of-the-cambridge-philosophical-society/article/div-classtitleon-square-values-of-quadraticsdiv/6DF585C26D4504B22DF90DB4A614D61F), Math Proc Camb Phil Soc 99 (1986) 381-383,

Duncan A Buell, Integer squares with constant second differences, Mathematics of Computation 49 (1987) 635-644, and

Andrew Bremner, [On square values of quadratics](https://eudml.org/doc/278007), Acta Arithmetica 108.2 (2003) 95-111.